# Unable to make objects with type synonyms : type

Tags: haskell

I am reading "Learn You A Haskell" and in chapter [typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), i am playing with this code :

```
type EmpData = String
data EmpPair = EmpPair EmpData EmpData deriving (Show)
type Colleagues = EmpPair 
data Team = Team Colleagues deriving (Show)
```

When i try to make an object of type `Team` , ghc gives :

```
*Main> Team (Colleagues "Ashish" "Ajay")

<interactive>:41:7: Not in scope: data constructor `Colleagues'
```

However, this is successful :

```
*Main> Team (EmpPair "Ashish" "Ajay")
Team (EmpPair "Ashish" "Ajay")
```

I do not understand why is this happening ? Please explain.

Comment: `type Colleagues = EmpPair` only creates a type synonym, not a data constructor synonym. So this is precisely the expected behaviour. Starting with GHC 7.8, you can do what you want with [pattern synonyms.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms)

Comment: cannot believe this.. i thought this to be so basic..

Comment: I have GHCi, version 7.8.3.. Do i need to do something else to enable this..

Comment: Place `{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}` at the *top* of your source file, then define anywhere in your module: `pattern Colleagues x y = EmpPair x y`.

Comment: I get on ghci ..`*Main> Team (Colleagues "Ashish" "Ajay") \r\n
Team (EmpPair "Ashish" "Ajay")`  I wished It would have printed "Colleagues" in its Show method of ghci.. Should not it ? Actually that was my actual curiosity behind writing this code in first place..

Comment: No, it should not. If you would like a custom show instance for `Team`, you should not derive it. Just write it by hand.

Comment: just last comment, do not understand why it should not.. Is their some logic ? It seems like "type synonyms" are like "C macros" that forget everything after they get replaced all over the source.. hope they would have more useful characteristics.. ?

Comment: @AshishNegi `type Colleagues = EmpPair` says that `Colleagues` is just another name for exactly the same type `EmpPair`. A type that displays differently via `show` is *not* the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you have to use something like:

```
Team (EmpPair "string1" "string2")
```

Haskell has separate name spaces for types and terms. That means a name may be defined as a type or as a term (a value or function) or as both, and the definitions may or may not be related to each other.

In your code here is what each name is:

```
data Team = Team Colleagues
      ^       ^       ^-- type
    type     term

type Colleagues = EmpPair
     type-^          ^-- type

data EmpPair = EmpPair EmpData EmpData
   type-^        ^       ^        ^      
               term     type    type
```

Compare this with an example of a multi-construtor type:

```
data Bool = True | False
      ^       ^      ^
    type     term   term
```

This says that to create a value of type Bool we can either use the function `True` or the function `False`.

When there is only one constructor for a type the convention is to use the same name for the type and the constructor name - i.e. your Team type.
However, there is no reason why you have to follow this. You could have decided to use, e.g.:

```
data Team = MakeTeam Colleagues
```

To create a value (term) of type Team, your original definition says we need to use the function `Team` with a value of type Colleagues.

The definition of `Colleagues` says that the type Colleagues is the same as the type EmpPair.

The definition for (the type) EmpPair says that to create a value of type EmpPair we need to use the function EmpPair with two values of type EmpData.

The definition of EmpData says that the type EmpData is the same as the type String.

Putting this all together, we can construct a value of type Team like this:

```
Team (EmpPair "string1" "string2")
```

You are getting the error message because Colleagues is not a term - it is only defined as a type.

**Update**

To answer your question in the comments about whether or not you should use PatternSynonyms, consider the following:

- PatternSynonyms are used in only about 35 packages (out of about 8400) on Hackage. Not only is it not used very much, but you can write a lot of useful code without it.
- Your particular use is very simple compared to other uses of PatternSynonyms. Most uses of PatternSynonyms are to create more elaborate layers of abstraction, but in this case you are just using it to create an alternate name for a constructor.
- You should ask yourself if you even want your users to have direct access to the Colleagues constructor. If you want to hide implementation details you are better off supplying alternatives for creating and accessing values within a Colleagues values, i.e. something like:

  ```
  mkColleagues :: EmpData -> EmpData -> Colleagues
  ...

  firstColleague :: Colleagues -> EmpData
  ...

  secondColleague :: Colleagues -> EmpData
  ...
  ```

Exposing only these functions potentially allows you to expand the Colleagues data type with additional fields without breaking the API.

Comment: Most of your explanation is sound, but you are missing parentheses (or `$`) in `Team (EmpPair "string1" "string2")`.

Comment: Thanks.. but i am able to do it with `PatternSynonyms`.. Can you comment on that too ? Would you recommend this or pattern-synonyms ?